# CakePHP not displaying page view but its code

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP. When trying to display the page in the "View" directory such as a file profile.ctp, i am getting an odd form being displayed. No pictures or sources such as css or javascripts. I believe it is not recognizing code formats such as below

```
<?= $this->Html->image($picture_url, array("class" => "profile-picture")); ?>
```

What is outputting on the page is this

```
Html->image($picture_url, array("class" => "profile-picture")); ?>
```

[image]

Please any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: What url are you requesting (are you requesting `http://localhost/View/Foo/profile.ctp` or equivalent)? What version of php are you using? What file contains "Learn more", "formattedName" and "headline" (show the whole view file)?

Comment: Don't use short tags and your image call is missing an echo in front.

Comment: [Note: Starting with PHP 5.4, short echo tag <?= is always recognized and valid, regardless of the short_open_tag setting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php). Unless they are using an old version of php - it's fine to use short echo, which is the only form that's in the question.

Comment: Thanx AD7six and burzum, i was on php5.3 and upgraded to 5.5 looking better now. at least for the images, still having issue on getting css and js scripts to work.

Comment: How do i give you guys credit, for the answer?

Comment: @AD7six can add his comment as an answer. Then you can upvote and accept his answer.

Comment: "still having issue on getting css and js scripts to work." doesn't sound like the problem is resolved - but it's unclear what "the problem" is. If the only error was using short tags and not having short tags enabled (with php pre 5.4) - that would make it a duplicate question.

Comment: Hey @AD7six, i did get to figure it out. there was a echo issue on the _header.cpt file. all is good now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a PHP/CakePHP problem, but a web server configuration problem.

Depending on the web server (Apache, Lighthttpd, IIS, ...), you must tell it somehow to recognize the `*.php` files as code being executed and not a page to be delivered.

To check, if the web server recognizes PHP files properly, you can create a simple page with just

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

If everything is configured properly, you should get a page with the PHP configuration information, like version, various settings and modules installed.

When `phpinfo` shows the expected output, everything is set up properly. Then you must enable [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag), in order to use `<?` and `<?=`.

Comment: Hi Olaf, I did run phpinfo() and was able to receive that information. but still unable to figure out the error.